# funções entrelaçadas com click

Tags: javascript

estou com o seguinte problema quando eu dou dois cliques no meu botão ele entrelaça o array fatiado anterior eu tentei matar o processo anterior com .remove() e também colocar null ao contador mais removia o elemento inteiro ou dava um erro o certo era apenas apagar o contador anterior para começar um novo

```html
  <body style="background-color: #444; color: #fff;">
  
  <script>

      var vidas = 0

      function lol() {

        

         if(vidas >= 5) {
          window.location.href = 'index.html'
        } else {

          vidas++

          balao = document.getElementById('balao')


          var textos = new Array()
          textos[1] = ' texto um'
          textos[2] = ' texto dois'
          textos[3] = ' texto três'
          textos[4] = ' texto quatro'
          textos[5] = ' texto cinco'

          negativo = document.getElementById('negativo')
          negativo_2 = document.getElementById('negativo_2')
          negativo.innerHTML = '- ' + vidas

          if(vidas === 5){
            negativo.remove()
            negativo_2.style.fontSize = '20px'
            negativo_2.innerHTML = '<span align="center"><h1><b>GAME</b><h2><b>OVER</b></h2><span>'

          }

          var corazon = document.getElementById('v' + vidas)
          corazon.remove()

          var flower_ = document.getElementById('flower')


          var contador = textos[vidas].split("");
          var timer;
          

          function loop () {
            if (contador.length > 0) {
              balao.innerHTML += contador.shift();
            } else {
              clearTimeout(timer);
                }
            loopTimer = setTimeout(loop,100);

          }

          loop();

        }
        
      }
  </script>


<span>* </span><span id="balao">texto zero </span>


      <div class="objects">

          <div class="vidas">
            <span id="negativo"></span><span id="negativo_2"></span><br>
            <img id="v1" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v2" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v3" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v4" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v5" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />
          </div>

<div class="mt_2">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn-go-home" onclick="lol()" data-tilt>Continue</a></div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Poxa amigo. Não tem como colocar na sua pergunta, pontos, vírgulas, para um melhor entendimento? E explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: execute o arquivo e clique duas vezes no botão de continue vc vera que e texto um e dois vão ser imprimidos juntos

Comment: vou tentar adicionar um botão de disable segundo minha função de segundo para ele não ser clicado novamente... mais eu realmente queria resolver isso vai que me deparo com isso de novo no futuro

Comment: Crie uma variável para controlar se o *loop* ainda está escrevendo, e só processe a próxima mensagem se não estiver: https://jsfiddle.net/b42d3c0a/

Comment: eu tinha feito com setimeout se vidas fosse maior que 2 mais isso é muito melhor valew<3 se vc poder responder a pergunta aqui no responder eu marco como resposta

Comment: seria bom mudar o nome do post admin para uma que melhor se enquadre nos parâmetros do meu pedido para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

o comentário que deu certo foi do user @hkotsubo

> Crie uma variável para controlar se o loop ainda está escrevendo, e só processe a próxima mensagem se não estiver: jsfiddle.net/b42d3c0a

```js
var vidas = 0;
var processar = true;
function lol() {
    if (!processar)
        return;

    processar = false;
    if (vidas >= 5) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else {
        vidas++;
        balao = document.getElementById('balao');

        var textos = new Array();
        textos[1] = ' texto um';
        textos[2] = ' texto dois';
        textos[3] = ' texto três';
        textos[4] = ' texto quatro';
        textos[5] = ' texto cinco';

        negativo = document.getElementById('negativo');
        negativo_2 = document.getElementById('negativo_2');
        negativo.innerHTML = '- ' + vidas;

        if (vidas === 5) {
            negativo.remove();
            negativo_2.style.fontSize = '20px';
            negativo_2.innerHTML = '<span align="center"><h1><b>GAME</b><h2><b>OVER</b></h2><span>';
        }

        var corazon = document.getElementById('v' + vidas);
        corazon.remove();

        var flower_ = document.getElementById('flower');

        var contador = textos[vidas].split("");
        function loop() {
            if (contador.length > 0) {
                balao.innerHTML += contador.shift();
                setTimeout(loop, 100);
            } else {
                processar = true;
            }
        }
        
        balao.innerHTML = ''

        loop();
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #444; color: #fff;">
<span>* </span><span id="balao">texto zero </span>
      <div class="objects">
          <div class="vidas">
            <span id="negativo"></span><span id="negativo_2"></span><br>
            <img id="v1" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v2" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v3" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v4" src="data:img/png;base64,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" width="25px" />

            <img id="v5" src="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAQAAACROWYpAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAHdElNRQflCAgOOiqLFXkaAAAA/0lEQVQ4y+2UzU4CMRSFv9YiiCGBhNGtPgmJYeuSp8DE5/CxXPIKLMQ30EwyUaaYy6J3kvmBCjNbThftac9p7u3PRRAEGUvAs/LDba6qJHALgGNAwB0Wq7NlXOG4pq9sFBRGwPLXEA/YlpjDNxQ9do6EEU3ck/Kt44TxAcWUXyPCMRjtjyosHRAzm//MLrL2ypBbhpHdIzl3CvtivpgBcKwB6PF4husLT05u9HU+sDnDPAl/vQg775Kzb2MuvmTKCwALZhH1OysyMn6U14rrm8SwrKrrV5W1ybmV2dQKSZ8bAD6YlGY3PJHjSSvVvFHDtrpcPX3P5ylhFzjp3juZ95CIf40YVJ6uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="25px" />
          </div>

<div class="mt_2">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn-go-home" onclick="lol()" data-tilt>Continue</a></div>
</body>
```